# Gnome black screen while booting

Tags: gnome

Recently I installed the gnome desktop on my Ubuntu 15.10 and when the computer is booting this screen appears:

[image]

Even though my computer boots normally I want to know what this could be. The last time something similar appeared to me I solved installing bumblebee for my nvidia graphic card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a black screen, it's running fsck. (file system consistency checker). It's normal for a computer to fsck itself on every boot. It's usually with a regular fsck but sometimes (I can't remember how often, I think it's like every 20 boots) it runs a full fsck, which is more thorough but takes longer.
Note DO NOT type any of those commands in terminal (with sudo). Mounted file systems should never be fscked unless you want severe data loss/ corruption.
Anyway your computer is telling you its data has a clean bill of health. So, hooray for you!